# Assume group algebra decomposition has no common factor then elements of decomposition are two sided ideals

Tags: representation-theory

In general if we have
$\mathbb CG=A\oplus B$ then writing $1=e_1+e_2$, with $e_1,e_2\in A,B$ respectively we have

$A=\mathbb CG e_1$  and $B=\mathbb CG e_2$

$e_1e_2=e_2e_1=0$
and $e_1^2=e_1$ and $e_2^2=e_2$

So assume $\mathbb CG=A\oplus B$ where $A,B$ can be considered left $\mathbb CG$ modules (left $\mathbb CG$ ideals) such that they have no common composition factor.

The irreducible/simple $\mathbb CG$ module $U$ is a composition factor of a bigger $V$ $\mathbb CG$ module if $V$ has sub $\mathbb CG$ module isomorphic to $U$.

I can also show that $$Hom_{\mathbb CG}(A,B)=Hom_{\mathbb CG}(B,A)=\{0\}$$

I want to show $A,B$ are also **right ideals** of $\mathbb CG$ .

So I take arbitrary $r=\sum r_g g\in \mathbb CG$

I want to show that given any $r_1e_1\in A=\mathbb CGe_1$

$$r_1e_1r\in \mathbb CGe_1$$

But after long hours I cannot conclude? Without using the assumption of common factor (which I cannot use properly ) i think no solution is possible...

Comment: Kindly state what your letters stand for. ("ℂ" is clearly the complex field.)

Comment: so yes, i meant it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_ring